# pack files on windows and preserve folder timestamps

Tags: windows, zip, gzip, archive, tar

I want to put a big folder on Windows box into one archive (tar, zip, gzip, whatever). Is there a tool that can preserver all folder timestamps?

The timestamps have to be preserverd after unpacking the archive on a Linux box.

Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: What do you mean by folder timestamps? Do you actually mean file time stamps? And which time stamps do you want preserved? Creation date? Modified date?

Comment: The modified date would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tar will do fine. gzip is for single file compression, zip won't preserve directory timestamps.

EDIT: Sample.

```
tar jcpf backup.tbz2 thedir
rm -rf thedir
tar jxpf backup.tbz2
```

Timestamps preserved.

EDIT2:

cygwin `tar` correctly preserves timestamps. Tested with `tar jcf` on cygwin, `tar jxf` on linux.

EDIT3:
WinRar preserves directory timestamps, linux `unrar` restores them properly.

Comment: tar is designed for tape archiving right, so presumably if tar couldn't do it what chance would anything have?

Comment: That's what I thought in the first place. I tried tar with 7zip and gnuwin32. But no luck. The folder timestamps are lost.

Comment: @BetaRide What is a folder timestamp? Do you mean folder time stamp or do you mean file timestamp?

Comment: tar preserves both folder and file timestamps for me. I'm using **tar** though, not some other archiver that happens to support tar format.

Comment: On Windows this code does not preserve folder timestamp. On my Ubuntu machine it does. Unfortunately I need a solution for creating the archive on Windows.

Comment: @David Heffernan What I mean is the last modification time stamp the folder.

Comment: @Erik is that better than gnuwin32 tar?

Comment: @David: Haven't used gnuwin32 - but my cygwin tar also preserves timestamps.

Comment: @Erik I've had problems with a cygwin tar that had a habit of producing weird security settings when extracting files. Could have been my cygwin though. I only had the DLL and not a full cygwin installation which I find somewhat invasive.

Comment: @David: cygwin's mapping of NTFS ACLs is semi-broken at best :)

Comment: I cannot do a full cygwin installation. Is there a way to deploy only tar from cygwin? I need a tool, that I can copy to a directory and execute without any further installation.

Comment: @BetaRide: WinRar apparently preserves timestamps.

Comment: @Erik: It seams that WinRar cannot access file shares :-(.

Comment: @Erik: EDIT2 is correct for a full cygwin installation. If you take only the necessary exe and dll files for tar and start this from a windows command line, timestamps are not preserverd.

Answer (score 0):

DotNetZip preserves timestamps on folders, as well as files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, DotNetZip is a very powerfull tool! It can indeed save folder timestamps.
Unfortunately I have to unzip on Linux. At least for Ubuntu unzip is not able to preserve the timestamps :-(.

Comment: FYI: Windows Explorer nor TotalCommander are able to preserve timestamps whenn unpacking zip archives, no matter wheter the zip file contains correct timestamps or not.

Comment: @BetaRide - seems like the problem is with the unzip utility on Ubuntu then, eh?  People have compiled DotNetZip on Mono - if you do that then you could use DotNetZip to unzip on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

It seams that there's no soluation to all my requirements:

1. Pack on Windows an preserve folder timestamps
2. Unpack on Linux and preserve original folder timestamps
3. I prefer a copy/paste aka portable installation of the tool, otherwise the deployment gets to complicated.
4. A partial, drop in cygwin installation by just copying the necessary exe and dll files works, but doesn't preserve the folder timestamps.
5. Full cygwin installation is not easily possible since the windows client machines are on terminal server (see http://www.cygwin.com/faq/faq.setup.html#faq.setup.setup-fails-on-ts)
6. Zip doesn't work because unzip on ubuntu cannot preserver folder timestamps, even if the zip tool of choice does.

Comment: Well the problem is unzip on Ubuntu.  If you can find or use a different unzip  on Ubuntu, you can solve your problem. For example, use DotNetZip on Mono on Ubuntu.